# Autodetect proxy settings in JavaFX - webview

Tags: java, webview, proxy, javafx-2, javafx

My browser (`webview`) starts with an `HTML` page

`FILEJAVA.class.getResource ("FILEHTML.html"). ToExternalForm ()`

I want ..
when I access the google him to check if the network has **proxy** (proxy'm working manual)

hence he takes and shows a dialog to enter User name and password.

`Javascript` or it is for the same `javafx`?

I thank you ..

Comment: Question is not clear. Who is 'he'? `..google him to check..`